# Identify what leads a boolean expression to be false

Tags: python, boolean

I have in input to my program an expression (whose output is always False) like:

`(var1 ==/!= var2) &&/|| (var3==/!=var4) &&/|| (var5==/!=var6)`

After parsing the variable values i obtain something like this

`"True/False and/or True/False and/or True/False"`

(with the "/" character I indicate the possible choices in that context)

Starting from this refined expression, I would like to identify among the values at stake which of them causes the expression to return false.

For example:

`True && True && False`

The result would be "3", meaning that the third value in the expression (the False value) causes the expression to return false.

In this example the expression is of length 3, but length can be arbitrary.

And has higher priority than or.

Thanks in advance.

I don't necessarily need the ready-made code, I need an idea to proceed.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Show your code - [mre] ans ask specific question

Comment: My idea was to go left to right until you find an AND with an operand set to false, but it doesn't work well, because AND has higher priority than OR

Comment: This question is kind of ill-defined. Let's say your Boolean expression is `a and b or not a and not b`, and we have `a is True` and `b is False`. Is it now `a` that is causing the expressions to be `False`, or is it `b`? If you flip either of them, the expression will become `True`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I only need one of them, a or b in your case.I just need one of the values that make the expression false.

Comment: I don't necessarily need the ready-made code, I need an idea to proceed.

Comment: @SvenMarnach It's `a`. Since both `and` and `or` short-circuit, `not b` is never evaluated. (Mathematically, you can't pick one or the other, but in Python you can.)

Comment: I still don't get it. I think you first need a better definition what exactly it means that "a value makes the expression false". I can see it for a conjunction like `a and b and c`, but not for more complex expressions.

Comment: @chepner If `a is False` and `b is True`, then `not b` will be evaluated.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Let's focus on expressions of length equal to three. It is assumed that the expression as a whole is false. My goal is to understand what makes it false.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I thought we were focusing on examples with specific values assigned to the variable, not the generic expression.

Comment: @chepner Since we are trying to figure out how the expression changes if the truth value of the variables changes, I was considering the expression as a function in two variables, but I agree that it's not quite clear what exactly we are focusing on here. :)

Comment: And we don't even need a complicated example in that case: `a and b` would suffice, because no one variable can make it true. Either `a` or `b` by itself can make the expression false.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to have

```
(var1 ==/!= var2) || (var3==/!=var4) || (var5==/!=var6)
```

then you have various cases to consider: if both 'joins' are OR, then the value pair that "makes the expression false" must be all 3 value pairs. So you won't get a 1/2/3 output - or you can, if you're happy to only know the first false value pair.

I think you should define what output you want from these various cases:

- the possible permutations of joins - both &&, both ||, && and ||, || and && = 4
- crossed with
- the possible permutations of inputs = 8

Of course the case where all three value pairs are TRUE does not exist according to your description so it only needs to be 7 for the latter.